# Can anything be done to mitigate the negative experience caused by bogus close votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I've recently been noticing a lot of questions with close votes, almost exclusively with 'unclear what you're asking' as the reason. In almost all of these cases, it's completely clear to me what the user is asking.

I maybe be noticing this because I tend to only look at questions on topics that I don't think are general knowledge, but it seems to me like users are often flagging these questions just because they don't understand the problem domain.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937977/how-can-i-debug-which-thread-has-an-object-locked-in-a-net-core-process-on-linu) I asked a while ago had one close vote with 'unclear what you're asking', though currently none, I'm guessing it went through the review queue.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53711941/how-to-get-global-state-that-is-set-by-setthreadexecutionstate-api) I just came across has not one, but two close votes. What the user is asking is 100% clear to me, having worked with the API they're asking about.

### But why does it even matter? A close vote is just a vote, it doesn't mean the question will be closed!

See the italicized text in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53720012/214796) provided by the poster in my second link.

They're asking a perfectly valid and understandable question that may not be easily answered by Google, and getting feedback that someone (who?) thinks that their question was not a good one.

I actually had to go and check how much reputation is required to cast a close vote. It turns out that it's only 15; I assumed it was much higher.

This is a terrible experience for users who are new and don't understand that just about anyone can vote to close their question, and that close votes don't really matter.

I think this is an issue that merits some attention. What are some options that could mitigate the negative perception of StackOverflow that this 'close all the things' behavior instills in new users?

Comment: 15 rep is to flag, you need 3000 repo to cast close/reopen votes.

Comment: Ah, that's my bad. I didn't realize they were separate. But that makes it even more concerning; why are users with over 3000 rep voting to close these questions?

Comment: This proposed duplicate is not related. The questions I'm using as example are completely understandable and answerable; if anyone disagrees, they're free to explain why (which would be significantly more constructive than just a close vote; maybe more detail on certain close votes is what is needed?)

Comment: That user was whining about votes in his answer, that doesn't belong in an answer.  Lousy question btw, he's asking about a perceived solution without describing the problem.  As-is, it isn't anything more than  "I called SetThreadExecutionState and look, it worked".  That doesn't solve anything, SO users don't encourage anybody to write pointless code.  Getting rid of it is hard to do when the question owner can't be convinced by votes and telling him he's doing it wrong is considered more of a "bad experience" by the site owners.  Voting is all we can do.

Comment: Also I know this was not central to your post, but about new users having a bad experience because of renegade close votes, [250 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) is the threshold where you can see close votes on your own questions. So unless the question actually gets put on hold the majority of new users will never see them

Answer (score 28):

> What are some options that could mitigate the negative perception of StackOverflow that this 'close all the things' behavior instills in new users?

We should start by being even more clear about the goal of this site: to be a long lasting, high quality repository of programming questions and answers. In turn, they will have to understand the following:

- Your questions will be evaluated to earn their position on this site, in a similar fashion to an exam or a peer-reviewed source.
- You are not guaranteed, nor entitled to receive an answer to your question.
- Curators may provide you guidance, but even that is not mandatory, and they do not have to justify their moderating actions (unless in egregious situations worth lifting at Meta, YMMV), nor should you be insisting that they get back to you. Our curator base is significantly smaller than the number of askers and answerers, and we are not in a good position to make their labour even harder.

This should be made clear to new users and veteran users alike.

On a side note, since you mentioned it: please do not dismiss close votes with the assumption that whoever did it does not understand the topic. It does not go well here, and after all, something must have brought them to the question in the first place, and most of the time it's because they are minimally acknowledged of it. Once they become one of the five required to close a question, the vote had its value. It mattered.